# Hiding an array picturebox c#

Tags: c#, winforms

This generates a picturebox

```
PictureBox[][] picturebox;

public void loadPictureBox()
{
    string path = @"../../Images/Catelogue/"; //set pathing
    string[] list = Directory.GetFiles(path, "*.jpg");
    //pictureboxCatelogue = new PictureBox[list.Length];
    //pictureboxCosplay = new PictureBox[list.Length];

    picturebox = new PictureBox[4][];

    for (int i = 0; i < 4; i++)
    {
        picturebox[i] = new PictureBox[list.Length];

        int y = 85, temp = 220, run = 0;
        for (int index = 13; index < list.Length; index++) // loads all pictures and create pictureboxes
        {
            picturebox[i][index] = new PictureBox();
            picturebox[i][index].Image = Image.FromFile(path + index + ".jpg");

            this.Controls.Add(picturebox[i][index]);
            temp = temp + 200;

            if (index % 4 == 0)
            {
                if (run != 0)
                    y = y + 200;
                run++;
                temp = 220;
            }

            picturebox[i][index].Location = new Point(temp, y);
            picturebox[i][index].Size = new Size(180, 180);
            picturebox[i][index].Name = Convert.ToString(index);
            picturebox[i][index].SizeMode = PictureBoxSizeMode.Zoom;
            picturebox[i][index].BackColor = Color.FromArgb(35, 35, 35);
            picturebox[i][index].Click += new System.EventHandler(PictureBox_Click);
        }
    }
}
```

I'm trying to hide a jagged array which is a picturebox in winsform c#, but i keep getting an error, is hiding a jagged array possible? This is the code that i'm having trouble with.

```
for (int i = 0; i < picturebox.Length; i++)
{
    picturebox[0][i].Hide();
}
```

This is the error i get

> ERROR : A first chance exception of type 'System.NullReferenceException' occurred in APPD Assignment 2.exe (Additional information: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Aren't you using the wrong length here?

```
for (int i = 0; i < picturebox.Length; i++)
```

Should be

```
for (int i = 0; i < picturebox[0].Length; i++)
```

When you load the pictureboxes, you're only starting at index 13, so you either need to start the hide loop at 13, or check for null.

```
for (int i = 13; i < picturebox[0].Length; i++)
{ ... }
```

or

```
for (int i = 0; i < picturebox[0].Length; i++)
{
    if (picturebox[0][i] != null) 
    {
        picturebox[0][i].Hide();
    }
}
```

Comment: Good spot, but I think he is also starting his index for the 2nd array dimension at 13 so still think you might need to start i at 13 or at a null check.

Comment: I tried changing to that, but there's still error :c the error points to the Hide(); part of the code

Comment: sorry, that 13 was for testing, it was suppose to start at 0, my bad! ''>.<

Comment: Thanks alot! it was the 13 part lol, i guess i need alittle break :D